# iOS hiding UIMenuContoller for good in all screens and with all UIControls

Tags: ios, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I am trying to disable the UIMenuController across the application and I am using the below code

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(menuWillBeShown) name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:nil];

-(void)menuWillBeShown
{
    UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menu setMenuVisible:NO];
    [menu performSelector:@selector(setMenuVisible:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] afterDelay:0.1]; //also tried 0 as interval both look quite similar

}
```

Everything works fine as the **menu comes up and disappears immediately**. I did a lot of research on this thing and this is the best I could do. Is there a better way?